# Creating a list in python from a string

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement

I have the following string:

```
'recipe : cake, cookies, pizza'
```

How would I remove the punctuation and the string "recipe" so that I would get the following output?

```
['cake', 'cookies', 'pizza']
```

The colon can be any type of punctuation.

So I tried multiple things that did not work, one using a for loop to iterate over string.punctuation and check if the punctuation was in the string after splitting it but it doesn't work. Please point me to the right direction. This is sort of what I was going for:

```
import string

string = 'recipe : cake, cookies, pizza'

for punctuation in string.punctuation:

     if punc in string:


 *Then split by that punctuation and by ',' while also removing whitespace. Pls help
```

Comment: Hi Sean, welcome to SO! Here's a hint: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp &  https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Answer (score 1):

1. take the part right of semicolon
2. split on commas
3. remove extra spaces

Altogether:

```
res = [s.strip() for s in recipe_str.split(':', 1)[-1].split(',')]
```

UPD:

to split on any of `string.punctuation`,

```
import re

res = [s.strip() for s in 
       re.split(r'[!"#$%&\'\(\)\*\+,-\./:;<=>\?@\[\]^_`\{|\}~]',
                recipe_str, 1)[-1].split(',')]
```

Comment: What if I want to split regardless of what punctuation is there? For instance, the colon could be any punctuation... how would I use string.punctuation in this case?

Comment: @SeanRotmansky please see the update. The regexp is just the escaped `string.punctuation`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to deal with this is to find all groups or words with:

```
import re

s = 'recipe : cake, cookies, pizza'

re.findall(r'\w+', s)[1:]
# ['cake', 'cookies', 'pizza']
```

`\w+` will match letters, numbers and the underscore: `_`.